Can anyone name this film about a group of misbehaving kids swearing and smoking redhead girl
Can anyone name this film, I watched it as a child,I think  the movie is from the late 70s or 80s.

if is about a group of kids who go off on adventures on their own and get into trouble, in places like woods / junk yards
the lead girl I think has very short (maybe curly) red hair and they swear a lot and smoke and drink (I think)
they are about 12 years old
At one point they climb up a water tower and one of the children nearly falls in
They were possibly looked after by a grandparent
it's set in America somewhere 

It is slightly reminiscent of Stand By Me, but it isn't that film 

12 years olds smoking and drinking and swearing... those were the good ole days.

That does fit my description, but its not unfortunately. The lead girl is the same age as them and has short very red hair. Thank you for answering though

I think it's The War, made in 1994 and set in the 70s. It stars Kevin Costner, and the girl is LaToya Chisholm.
Is it okay to post IMDb links here?
IMDb: The War (1994)

Welcome to the community. You can and you should include a link to IMDb (or similar). Please also include your reasons for believing that this the answer. I hope you like it here.
